# Applying Jake's remez exchange algorithm for filter design

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response

I have found C implementation for remez exchange algorithm(https://github.com/janovetz/remez-exchange/blob/master/remez.c) and I want to use this to implement a generic prototype lowpass filter. Although the comments have been provided to guide on how to use it I am having trouble implementing it. Could anyone tell me what are the correct inputs which I am suppose to give to the remez() function to get coefficients for lowpass filter because I suspect I am not providing the correct inputs.

**EDIT:**  I have been reading and experimenting with the code and I found out that for lowpass filter I should give type as 1(i.e Bandpass). Anyhow just to try the code I gave the parameters for bandpass filter in MATLAB and same parameters to remez() but the results are very different. Could somebody have a look at my coefficients and tell me what I am doing wrong because I don't get it?

**MATLAB:**

```
% All frequency values are in Hz.
Fs = 2000;  % Sampling Frequency
Fstop1 = 200;              % First Stopband Frequency
Fpass1 = 300;              % First Passband Frequency
Fpass2 = 700;              % Second Passband Frequency
Fstop2 = 800;              % Second Stopband Frequency
Dstop1 = 0.000177827941;   % First Stopband Attenuation
Dpass  = 0.0057563991496;  % Passband Ripple
Dstop2 = 0.000177827941;   % Second Stopband Attenuation
dens   = 20;               % Density Factor
% Calculate the order from the parameters using FIRPMORD.
[N, Fo, Ao, W] = firpmord([Fstop1 Fpass1 Fpass2 Fstop2]/(Fs/2), [0 1 ...
                           0], [Dstop1 Dpass Dstop2]);
```

These values (N, Fo, Ao, W) obtained from MATLAB, I feed to remez() function.

**So the C++ function looks like:** (just the part where I am calling the remez function)

```
int numtaps = 64;
int numbands = 3;
std::vector<double> h(numtaps);
double  bands[] = [0, 0.2000, 0.3000, 0.7000, 0.8000, 1.000];
double  des[] = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0];
double weight[] = [0.000177827941, 0.0057563991496, 0.000177827941];
int type = 1;
int griddensity = 20;
remez(&(h[0]), int *numtaps, int *numband, const double bands[], const double des[], const double weight[], int *type, int *griddensity);
```